# use a reactiveVal in renderText({})

Tags: shiny

I have a table where I get a value from the same column but from different rows and I would like to display in a *verbatimTextOutput* each value without overwriting each time.

I tried to do that but I get an error:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),   
  verbatimTextOutput("output", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  val <- reactiveVal(as.character(dt[input$table_rows_selected, 2]))
  o <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
    o(c(o(), "\n", "You chose :", val()))
    output$output <- renderText({ o() })
  })

  dt <- data.frame("a" = paste("a", 1:10), "b" = paste("b", 1:10))
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(dt, selection = list(target = 'row'))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Comment: Not sure what you want. It'd help if you add more info on the desired behavior.

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but if you write `val <- reactive(as.character(dt[input$table_rows_selected, 2]))` instead of `reactiveVal` it's working.

Comment: hello, Excuse me if I didn't explain it very well.  @gdevaux find the solution.